# how to show a pop up or alert notification when someone taps the dictation button on the keyboard in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm new to Xamarin so this might be a simple question. I work for a healthcare solutions company and we are building a Xamarin Forms shared app for iOS and Android. We want to inform the user of a possible HIPPA violation when they tap the dictation button on the keyboard because they could be talking about personal information. In iOS it's pretty simple when the microphone button is tapped it changes the keyboard mode to "dictation", but in Android I can't find any documentation on how to know that the button has been tapped so we can show the alert. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I could not find any way to handle an event when the microphone button is pressed. Perhaps it will suffice just to disable the microphone button? If so, you can try this:

```
// In code
editText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText1);
editText.PrivateImeOptions = "nm,com.google.android.inputmethod.latin.noMicrophoneKey";

// In layout file
<EditText
    ...
    android:privateImeOptions="nm, com.google.android.inputmethod.latin.noMicrophoneKey" 
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have also seen that the mic can be hidden and have talked this over with my team. We think there would be a lot of negative responses if we didn't allow dictation. So I'm hoping there's another way of doing this.